# Git clone and npm install permission denied (publickey)

Tags: git, npm

I cloned existing repo (not mine) via https. After that I am trying to install something , for example :

> npm install angularfire2/storage

And then I get error :

```
npm ERR! Error while executing:
npm ERR! C:\Program Files\Git\cmd\git.EXE ls-remote -h -t ssh://git@github.com/angularfire2/storage.git
npm ERR!
npm ERR! git@github.com: Permission denied (publickey).
npm ERR! fatal: Could not read from remote repository.
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Please make sure you have the correct access rights
npm ERR! and the repository exists.
npm ERR!
npm ERR! exited with error code: 128
```

I understood that I don't have rights to write in this repo. Then I tried to move it to mine repo (git set url) but that didn't helped.

**How to make that I could write anything to it ?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This means, on your local machine, you haven't made any SSH keys. Not to worry. Here's how to fix:
https://help.github.com/articles/adding-a-new-ssh-key-to-your-github-account/